# Spring kafka - retry sending the message in case of failure on same partition and offset

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I am using kafkaTemplate to send messages to kafka topic . I came across an requirement which says in case if there is a failure while sending the messages to kafka topic then I should retry sending message on same partition with same offset.  Kindly help on how this can be achieved using kafkatemplate ?

Comment: Retries are automatically performed by the underlying `KafkaProducer`. https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#producerconfigs_retries

Comment: "should retry sending message on same partition with same offset" , this is not a valid requirement. If you have multiple producers writing to same topic OR the topic is a multi-partitioned one with null key, Kafka producer cannot guarantee the same partition/offset in retry. Better to re-validate this point. Retries can just ensure that event is posted but not into same location which it tried earlier.

Answer (score 0):

You can retry the message using the standard retry mechanism and you can use the CustomPartitioners to send the message always to a specific partition, based on a Keying scheme. But offset is something, you can't predict in advance, because it is only be returned in the Record Metatdata via Java Future, only when Broker Acknowledges your message.

Better you can re-validate your requirements here.